# Is this correct? (past tense vs past perfect)

Tags: tense, past-vs-past-perfect

1. I ***thought*** you would have picked him up from school.
2. I ***had thought*** you would have picked him from school.

In the first case "thought" verb on the timeline comes ***after*** the "picking" verb.

In the second case "thought" verb on the timeline comes ***before*** the "picking" verb.

Am I correct with this logic? If I am, then why do native speakers use these two sentences interchangeably?

Context:

Someone's  kid was supposed to be picked from the school at 1 p.m. The mother at 2 p.m. angrily scolds her husband for being careless for not picking his/her son up from school.

If she used (2) then that would mean "thought" verb came before before 1 p.m., expecting her husband to pick his son up later.

If she used (1) then that would mean "thought" verb came after 1 p.m., let's say 1:30 p.m. expecting her husband to have already picked up her son.

Am I correct with this line of reasoning?

Comment: Can you please edit this to give us the full context of the story? To answer it, I'll have to refer to specific points in time.

Comment: I have added the context, pls gimme your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is correct. 2 is incorrect, but you still might here people say it.

Sentence 1 and 2 both mean exactly what you have guessed in your question.

The problem in sentence 2 is that "would have picked him up" refers to a time previous to "think". But in sentence 2, the mother is having this thought before 1 pm, so *the child should not have been picked up yet*. At 1 pm, she would have thought, "My husband ***is going to*** pick him up", so a correct version of sentence 2 could be:

> 2a) I'd thought you ***were going to pick him up***.

This is the reported speech back-shifted version of her actual thought before 1pm.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131423/discussion-on-answer-by-gotube-is-this-correct-past-tense-vs-past-perfect).